# Array destructuring via spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) concerning array destructuring is pretty self-explanatory, however, I fail to understand what is happening behind the scenes when destructuring an array like so:

```js
let Arr = [1, 3, 5, 6];
let newArr = [];

[newArr[0], ...newArr] = Arr;

console.log(Arr); // returns [1, 3, 5, 6]
console.log(newArr); // returns [3, 5, 6]
```

How is it that `newArr` does not inherit the first array member of `Arr`?

Comment: A quick tip for understanding more recent syntax like this: Paste the code you don't understand into the Babel repl and compare the input / output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had

```
[x, ...y] = Arr;
```

it would be like

```
x = Arr[0];
y = Arr.slice(1);
```

so when you have

```
[newArr[0], ...newArr] = Arr;
```

it’s like

```
newArr[0] = Arr[0];
newArr = Arr.slice(1);
```

The assignments involved in destructuring happen left to right. Live:

```js
const listener = {
  get foo() {
    return {
      set bar(value) {
        console.log('setting bar');
      },
    };
  },
  set foo(value) {
    console.log('setting foo');
  },
};

[listener.foo.bar, ...listener.foo] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it overwrites with the rest parameters the first value on index zero.

```js
let array0 = [1, 3, 5, 6],
    array1 = [],
    array2 = [];

[array2[0], ...array1] = array0;

console.log(array0); // [1, 3, 5, 6]
console.log(array1); // [3, 5, 6]
console.log(array2); // [1]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```